# Can I cache after using std::make_shared?

Tags: c++, effective-c++

I am reading Effective Modern C++ (Scott Meyers) and trying out something from item 21. The book says a side effect of using `std::make_shared` is that memory cannot be freed until all `shared_ptr`s and `weak_ptr`s are gone (because the control block is allocated together with the memory).

I expected that this would mean that if I keep a cache around holding a bunch of `weak_ptr`s that no memory would ever be freed. I tried this using the code below, but as the shared_ptrs are removed from the vector, I can see using pmap that memory is actually being freed. Can anyone explain me where I am going wrong? Or if my understanding is wrong?

Note: the function `loadWidget` is not the same as in the book for the purpose of this experiment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

class Widget {
public:
  Widget()
    : values(1024*1024, 3.14)
  { }

  std::vector<double> values;
};

std::shared_ptr<Widget> loadWidget(unsigned id) {
  return std::make_shared<Widget>();
}

std::unordered_map<unsigned, std::weak_ptr<Widget>> cache;

std::shared_ptr<Widget> fastLoadWidget(unsigned id) {
  auto objPtr = cache[id].lock();

  if (!objPtr) {
    objPtr = loadWidget(id);
    cache[id] = objPtr;
  }

  return objPtr;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Widget>> widgets;
  for (unsigned i=0; i < 20; i++) {
    std::cout << "Adding widget " << i << std::endl;
    widgets.push_back(fastLoadWidget(i));

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
  }
  while (!widgets.empty()) {
    widgets.pop_back();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
  }
  
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux make that an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that when you use `std::make_shared` the storage for the new object and for the control block is allocated as a single block, so it is not released as long as there exists a `std::weak_ptr` to it. But, when the last `std::shared_ptr` is destroyed the object is nonetheless destroyed (its destructor runs and its members are destroyed). It's just the associated storage which remains allocated and unoccupied.

`std::vector` allocates storage dynamically for its elements. This storage is external to the `std::vector`, it is not part of the object's memory representation. When you destroy a `Widget` you also destroy its `std::vector` member. That member's destructor will release the dynamically allocated memory used to store its elements. The only memory that can't be release immediately is the control block and the storage for `Widget` (which should be `sizeof(Widget)` bytes). It does not prevent the storage for the elements of the vector from being released immediately.

Comment: Yes, thanks! Such a silly error. When I replace it with an array of doubles it behaves as expected :)